# Existence of Brownian motion on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, uniform-distribution

Let $\mathscr A$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on the unit interval $[0,1]$, and $\mathbb P$ the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathscr A$. Is there a Wiener process aka Brownian motion on the probability space $([0,1],\mathscr A,\mathbb P)$?

This can of course be reformulated as follows: There is a measurable function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^{\mathbb R_+}$ such that for any uniform $U$, $f(U)$ is a Brownian motion (!).

Do you have a nice argument for the right answer?

---

Answer is given in a comment. As there is an i.i.d. sequence of uniforms on this space, we get an i.i.d. sequence of suitable normals which we can indeed use to construct Brownian motion on a dyadic grid and then "continuously" extend it, following P. Lévy. Thanks @geetha290krm.

Comment: You can construct i.i.d. normal r.v.'s on this space and use it to construct Brownian Motion.